# Binding Jar Library

Tags: android, xamarin.android, java-binding

I'm trying to bind a jar library (jCIFS) on MFA, but i'm stuck on some errors, like this one:

'Jcifs.Util.MD4' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Java.Security.MessageDigestSpi.EngineDigest()

After some research, i found some topics about this, telling to edit the metadata to change the permissions of the classes, like this:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='java.security']/class[@name='MessageDigestSpi']/method[@name='engineDigest']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

But the error didn't change, and a still won't get what this error means.

Anyone ?

**Edit**: This's the code of virtual class who return me the error:

```
    public virtual byte[] EngineDigest ()
    {
        if (id_engineDigest == IntPtr.Zero)
            id_engineDigest = JNIEnv.GetMethodID (class_ref, "engineDigest", "()[B");

        if (GetType () == ThresholdType)
            return (byte[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod  (Handle, id_engineDigest), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (byte));
        else
            return (byte[]) JNIEnv.GetArray (JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod  (Handle, ThresholdClass, id_engineDigest), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef, typeof (byte));
    }
```

And i added this in a new file:

```
partial class MD4
{
    public override byte[] EngineDigest()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If i do that, this error is returned:

*Error  1   Type 'Jcifs.Util.MD4' already defines a member called 'EngineDigest' with the same parameter types*

From what I understand, the method EngineDigest already exists, but the class needs to implement it. How i do that ?

The full error: *Error  195 'Jcifs.Util.MD4' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Java.Security.MessageDigestSpi.EngineDigest()*'

**Edit 2:** I've tried to reply the problem using OsmDroidBinding example from xamarin site. I edited the metafile until i get a similar error. And one of the lines i found was this one:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.osmdroid.tileprovider']/class[@name='MapTileProviderBase.ScaleTileLooper']/method[@name='handleTile']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

And i get this error:
[image: Error]

Then i tried to add this to my project metafile (like above), but the error persists:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='java.security']/class[@name='MessageDigestSpi']/method[@name='engineDigest']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is telling you that the generated class Jcifs.Util.MD4 doesn't implement an inherited abstract method. An abstract method is a method which must be overridden by any derived class.

The code below is changing the visibility of the base class's method to public, which obviously won't fix the problem.

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='java.security']/class[@name='MessageDigestSpi']/method[@name='engineDigest']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

There are several ways you could fix this error. Perhaps the easiest would be to add a class file to your Java Binding Library and add the following code to it.

```
namespace Jcifs.Util
{
    public partial class MD4
    {
        public override void EngineDigest()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE** You will need to change the return type of `EngineDigest()` to the return type defined for the abstract method in the base class. You haven't mentioned the return type in your question so I made it `void`.

Comment: I'm lacking some C# skills, so i can't get anywhere. If i add this code VS returns me "... already defines a member called EngineDigest with same parameter types. I'll edit the question for more information

Answer (score 0):

Change

public override byte[] EngineDigest ()

To

protected override byte[] EngineDigest ()